Merge attempt failed Base branch requires signed commits. Rebase merges cannot be automatically signed by GitHub
I want to rebase and merge a PR. But this error comes - Merge attempt failed Base branch requires signed commits. Rebase merges cannot be automatically signed by GitHub even when I performed signed commits.I have tried it on the GitHub website.I don't want to raise a new PR.
How to solve this problem?
